# Showing array value as the number in the array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, cakephp

Currently my code shows the year from 1885 to 2017.
What this does is show the years like so 0 = 1885, 1 = 1886.

What I want is that it shows it like this 1885 = 1885, 1886 = 1886 etc. (This resembles the date a car is built)

```
$options = [];
for ($x = 1885; $x <= date("Y"); $x++) {
array_push($options, $x);
}

  echo $this->Form->select('year', [
       $options,
   ],[
     'label' => false,
     'class' => 'form-group form-control',
   ]);
```

So I was wondering how to fix what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ($x = 1885; $x <= date("Y"); $x++) {
    $options[$x] = $x;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Also, you made script load faster by removing `array_push` call and using a language construct to append array variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this using `range()` and `array_combine()`:-

```
$years = range(1985, date('Y'));
$options = array_combine($years, $years);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the keys of the `$options` array as the keys are used as values to be submitted. You can as well benefit from using the `range` function to generate the array:

```
$values = array_map('strval', range(1885, (int) date("Y")));
$options = array_combine($values, $values);
```

Comment: The first answer works better for me, it's less complicated. But still I appreciate your answer!

Comment: yes, the first answer is easier to read, you could unroll the example I give here a little to make it more readable.